How to name the tag for Emergency free to play on Steam?
There's the tag emergency-20 which was created on my initiative. I think it's wrong because I was refererring to Emergency free to play on Steam which is not Emergency 20 apparently.
So, the tag should be renamed, I'm not sure about the right name, tough. emergency would refer rather to the series and emergency-free-to-play is a bit like advertising, however the best I can come up with.

Can you edit this post with links to the questions that should be retagged ? The current state of those posts (at least 2 of the 3) all mention "emergency 20" it seems, so if they are only about "emergency", they should be edited to reflect that as well

@TimmyJim I did the edits, good point. The questions to be retagged are https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/408098/how-to-win-attack-on-sub-station-in-emergency-20 https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/407831/how-to-prevent-fire-spread-exceeding-maximal-firefighting-capacity-in-emergency and https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405753/how-to-turn-off-electricity-in-an-area-with-an-electrical-fault

The tag emergency should be fine for that game. The tag emergency-series would be used for the series.

Sounds good, can you rename it, please?

There are 3 questions with that tag. You can just retag them yourself. Tag renames are primarily for when there are so many questions that retagging them all one by one is impractical.

OK, I can retag them, however I do not have the reputation (300) to create the new tag.

I've edited these posts to have the tag emergency:

How to win "attack on sub-station" in Emergency?
How to prevent fire spread exceeding maximal firefighting capacity in Emergency?
How to turn off electricity in an area with an electrical fault?

The system will automatically delete the emergency-20 tag when the job that does so runs if no questions are asked for it by then (I believe its a weekly job, so may be a bit before it gets deleted).
